# PyChar: navigate all, files and classes at once

Tags: pycharm

I try to learn PyCharm. Is there a "navigate all" dialog?

Up to now I could only find a dialog which searches either in files or in class names.

Would be nice to have both searches at once (with auto-complete)

Comment: Do you use ctrl+shift+r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-tap the SHIFT button to activate Search Everywhere.

Comment: SHIFT-SHIFT is great! Thank you